# A curve with positive curvature is asymptotic if and only if its binormal is parallel to the unit normal of the surface

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

I want some one explain to me; this part is not clear to me.

> **Q:** Show that curve $c$ with positive curvature is asymptotic if and only if if its binormal $B$ is parallel to the unit normal of $S$ at all points of $c$
>
> **A:** Since $K_n=0 \iff$  $c''$ is perpendicular to $N$ $\iff$ $N$ is perpendicular to $n$ $\iff$ $N$ is parallel to $B$ (since $N$ is perpendicular to $T$).

Here, $c''$ is the second derivative, $B$ binormal vector, $K_n$ normal curvature.

My question is

1. I know from Frenet–Serret formulas that $N$ is perpendicular to $B$ and $N$ is perpendicular to $T$ and $B$ is perpendicular to $T$. In the question it changes, it said that $N$ is parallel to $B$. Why did this change? Can any one explain this part please?
2. Why is $N$ perpendicular to $n$? Where this come from?

These are my questions, I hope someone can help me to understand please. If possible, draw a figure. Thank you.

Comment: When you write the word "equivalent", do you mean the symbol $\equiv$ ? Please note that you can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: @leena adam Some of your questions **might** be answered [here](http://math.uga.edu/~shifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

Comment: I think the OP is using "equivalent" to mean "iff."

Comment: this i mean equivalent <=>

Comment: Why is this question tagged algebraic-geometry?  This is not algebraic geometry, it is differential geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have the following setup: The curve $c$ lies in the surface $S$, which has unit normal vector $n$.  We let $\{T, N, B\}$ denote the Frenet frame of $c$.  We also let $\kappa$ denote the curvature of $c$, and $\kappa_n$ the normal curvature of $c$.  We can assume that $c$ is parametrized by arc length.

By the Frenet formulas, $c'' = T' = \kappa N$.  Since $\kappa_n = c'' \cdot n$, we have

$$\begin{align*}
\kappa_n = 0 & \iff c'' \perp n \\
& \iff \kappa N \perp n \\
& \iff N \perp n \\
& \iff B \parallel n.
\end{align*}$$

In answer to your questions:

1. There is a typo in what you wrote.  It should be that $B$ is parallel to $n$ (not $N$).  But why is this true?  Well, $n$ always lies in the plane spanned by $N$ and $B$ (because $n$ is perpendicular to $T$), so if $n$ is perpendicular to $N$, then $n$ must be parallel to $B$.
2. Because $c'' = \kappa N$ is parallel to $N$.

Comment: thank you very much great explain